# Is there a more efficient way to use *ngIf conditional

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have yes/no radio buttons that I'm reading the values from which are stored in a JSON object. First I'm checking to see if the json object is empty or if the field for the radio buttons is null. In that case I'm displaying both radio buttons unchecked. Next, I'm checking if the true value appears for the field in the json object and if so checking the yes radio button and likewise then checking for the false value and checking the no radio button. It seems like I'm using a lot of the same or similar code in the view though and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this. Here is what my code looks like. Thanks.

```
            <!-- json array will be empty when first coming to page, display no boxes checked -->
            <div *ngIf="(questions | json) === '{}' || questions.partYear == null">
              <input type="radio" id="yesRadio" formControlName="partYear" name="partYear" value="yes" [(ngModel)]="questions.partYear">Yes<br/>
              <input type="radio" id="noRadio" formControlName="partYear" name="partYear" value="no" [(ngModel)]="questions.partYear">No
            </div>

            <!-- user comes back to page, populate box that was checked during sesssion -->
            <div *ngIf="questions?.partYear === 'yes' || questions?.partYear === true">
              <input type="radio" id="yesRadio" formControlName="partYear" name="partYear" value="yes" checked [(ngModel)]="questions.partYear">Yes
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="questions?.partYear === 'no' || questions?.partYear === false">
              <input type="radio" id="yesRadio" formControlName="partYear" name="partYear" value="yes" [(ngModel)]="questions.partYear">Yes
            </div>

            <div *ngIf="questions?.partYear === 'yes' || questions?.partYear === true">
              <input type="radio" id="noRadio" formControlName="partYear" name="partYear" value="no" [(ngModel)]="questions.partYear">No
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="questions?.partYear === 'no' || questions?.partYear === false ">
              <input type="radio" id="noRadio" formControlName="partYear" name="partYear" value="no" checked [(ngModel)]="questions.partYear">No
            </div>
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this introduction](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-binding-radiobutton-lists/) to radio buttons in Angular. The first step I would do to improve your code is to move radio button 1 & 3 into one div and 2 & 4 into another, since they seem to have the same `*ngIf` conditions.

Comment: you can use ngSwitch

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this and negate the need for any *ngIf statements altogether.

```
<div>  
    <input type="radio" id="yesRadio" formControlName="partYear" name="partYear" [checked]="questions?.partYear === 'yes' || questions?.partYear === true" (click)="questions.partYear = 'yes'">Yes<br/>
    <input type="radio" id="noRadio" formControlName="partYear" name="partYear" [checked]="questions?.partYear === 'no' || questions?.partYear === false" (click)="questions.partYear = 'no'">No
</div>
```